# generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments - error while trying to create TF Record files for test and train data

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

While using the generate_tfrecord.py, I'm always getting this error of "generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments".

But, I haven't changed anything, and I've used the same command from the custom object detection tutorial, from the TFOD website.
Link: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

Tried both on Google Collab and also on local python environment, still same issue.

Anyone has experienced this error before, if so, how did you solve it? Please help. Thanks!

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x [PATH_TO_IMAGES_FOLDER]/train -l [PATH_TO_ANNOTATIONS_FOLDER]/label_map.pbtxt -o [PATH_TO_ANNOTATIONS_FOLDER]/train.record
```

Changes I made:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x C:/Users/prana/Desktop/cnn_system/images/train -l C:/Users/prana/Desktop/cnn_system/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o C:/Users/prana/Desktop/cnn_system/annotations/train.record
```

On Collab, I tried this:

```
!python generate_tfrecord.py -i /content/trainingdemo/images/train -l /content/trainingdemo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /content/trainingdemo/annotations/train.record
```

All the files have been double checked, they all exist in the right path.

Comment: Hi! Could you try again after converting image dataset  to csv file .                            
Reference  
https://github.com/niranjangavade98/TensorFlow-Custom-Object-Detection https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/Tony607/object_detection_demo/blob/master/tensorflow_object_detection_training_colab.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, it may work for someone else.

Try not to leave any spaces in the line of code, replace spaces with _

BEFORE:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/images/train -l D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/labelmap.pbtxt -o D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/train.record
```

AFTER:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x D:/Semestre/graduation_project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/images/train -l D:/Semestre/graduation_project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/labelmap.pbtxt -o D:/Semestre/graduation_project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/train.record
```

I had a space between graduation project

Comment: If you're typing code, you should use the format for code like so: `python generate_tfrecord.py`. If you need help with formatting please see: [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. After a whole day of search I figured out the solution!
We need to put those file names in inverted comma ("myFile") which have blank space in their names(my File).

Example:
Convert this:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/images/train -l D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/labelmap.pbtxt -o D:/Semestre/graduation project/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/train.record
```

To this:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py -x D:/Semestre/"graduation project"/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/images/train -l D:/Semestre/"graduation project"/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/labelmap.pbtxt -o D:/Semestre/"graduation project"/files/TensorFlow/workspace/training/annotations/train.record
```

In Short : put those filenames in inverted commas who are having space in between.
My Files to "My Files"

Hope this would help:)